Extracting a string from a larger value, where this string position is fixed but length can vary - in XSLT
I have a string as follows:
xri:roughgoing:QE1_300:whatwasthis:majorleague:FC:Hungary
From this, I need to extract "QE1_300".
I was considering using matches() or tokenize() in combination with some regex.
Would someone be able to suggest the best method?
<xsl:for-each select="myRef['[^:]*']">
 <xsl:if test="position() = 2">{.}</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>


The big question is, what is the GENERAL form of the input? An example is not a specification. If you want to extract the string between the second and third colons, that would be a specification. (Although an incomplete one, because we also need to know what happens if there are less than three colons...)

Not sure what you mean by "fixed position".
Assuming you want to extract the substring between the 2nd and 3rd colon, you could do simply:
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize($yourString, ':')[3]"/>

Of course, this is assuming your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher.
